# Get Bound Elements in event listener using Javascript or Selenium Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am trying to make a program that identifies "grouped elements" (it's complicated to explain but the blue box is the "grouped element").  If one selects an element that falls under the "grouped element" how does one return the elements that are listed under event listeners either through Javascript or Selenium Java? I'm trying to get the element in the red circle in the picture in link below. **The picture should make it clear what I'm trying to get.**

[image: snapshot]

Comment: ... if only there was a picture, to begin with

Comment: Just realized link had been hidden. The link is now active.

Comment: @Percy Update the question with your code trials, relevant HTML and error stack trace. Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.